# How can I get Live Location in telegram bot via python?

Tags: python, location, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using the `python-telegram-bot` library.
I want to track a user's Live Location, but I don't know how to do it.
I try to use Job Queue:

```
def notification(bot, job):
  updates = bot.get_updates()
  print([u.message.location for u in updates])
# Add job to queue

job = job_queue.run_repeating(notification, 10, 1, context=chat_id)
chat_data['job'] = job
```

But updates are void.
I want to track location every 1 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

Just to ellaborate on Seans answer:
It can be done quite easily using the python-telegram-bot library. Whenever the location did update it can be found in `update.edited_message`. This only works if the user is manually sharing live location with the bot of course.

```
def location(bot, update):
    message = None
    if update.edited_message:
        message = update.edited_message
    else:
        message = update.message
    current_pos = (message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude)

location_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.location, location)
dispatcher.add_handler(location_handler)
```

Comment: Just an update for 2019, the mentioned `edited_updates=True` is now unnecessary; it will now yield a `TelegramDeprecationWarning`. The [Transition Guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0#messagehandler) will essentially say, it now accepts all updates by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your updates should [look like this](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getUpdates-ff149865).

It will only contain first location in `.message.location`, the latest location is `.edit_message.location`, and others will be gone, so you need to record yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because `.edited_message` available only when user manually edit message. When user send Live Location, it doesn't update automatically.

Comment: @PavloZub does that mean there's no way at all to get automatic location updates of user sharing location using api?

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple function:

```
def location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    current_pos = (update.message.location.latitude,update.message.location.longitude)
    print(current_pos)

dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location, location))
```